# Trying to add info to objects in a array

Tags: java, arrays

So guys just doing a assignment and trying to add names, course and id to a array and looking for a cleaner way than i currently do. What i do currently achieves what i want but im sure their is a cleaner way to do it as if i had 100 of these to do it would take forever

```
    students[0].setName("John Doe");
    students[1].setName("Jane Doe");
    students[2].setName("John Smith");

    students[0].setCourse("2BA");
    students[1].setCourse("2BA");
    students[2].setCourse("2BSc");

    students[0].setID(44444444);
    students[1].setID(23333333);
    students[2].setID(22222222);
```

Comment: If you need to add 100 unique objects then you need to do it a 100 times, no way around that. You could have somewhat less code if your class has a suitable constructor so you could do `students[0] = new Student("John Doe", "2BA", 4444444);`. It would probably be easier to read as well. Next step would be to store the data in a file and create your objects from that but that might not be part of the assignment.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson  thanks buddy, i modified my setter as i like your way more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information about the underlying object behind each array entry, but you could create them as one-liners with constructor parameters.

```
class MyArrayObject {
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private long id;

    public MyArrayObject(String name, String course, long id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

...and then fill you array like that

```
students[0] = new MyArrayObject("John Doe", "2BA", 444444);
students[1] = new MyArrayObject("Jane Doe", "2BA", 445566);
students[2] = new MyArrayObject("John Smith", "2BSc", 442200);
```

It's still spaghetti code, but less.

To give you a better answer, we need more information about the object, where it comes from, what data sources you have, why you use such hardcoded values anyway.

Comment: Like the guy above, you have it right buddy. Its just a basic setter & getter im doing, this shortens it

Answer (score 0):

Real Applications never takes business values in Hard coded fashion, as you are doing here. They generally accepts values from user input, DBs or some other systems, and uses loops for processing of collections and array based data structures. 
If you are populating data for unit test cases, than using Student class constructor is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file that contains your data. You may chose any format (XML, json, CSV, etc).
Lets say you chose CSV which is one of the simplest formats to represent your data.
Each line on your CSV would contain:

Name, Course, ID

Write some code to read the file line by line into a String. Then for each line (each String) you can do:

```
String [] studentsStr = line.split(',');
```

Then your array will hold 3 Strings at indexes:

1: Name  2: Course  3: ID

As your CSV file could contain a non-deterministic size of students, you can use an ArraList.

Declare the array list

```
List<Student> studentL = new ArrayList<>();
```

For each line on the CSV text file:

```
Student std = new Student();
std.setName(studentsStr[0]);
std.setCourse(studentsStr[1]);
std.setID(studentsStr[2]);
studentL.add(std);
```

Then you can add as many students as you want into your CSV without any changes in your code.